# Loop of plots in R

Tags: arrays, r, loops, if-statement, plot

I have an array of N*C*T

I wish to plot a time series, acf and pacf for each row (i.e. for each N in the array)

I can do this in a single example

```
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
x <- x_whole[N,C,(1:T)]
plot(x, t='l')
abline(h=mean(x), col='red')
acf(x, lag.max=T-10)
pacf(x, lag.max=T-10)
```

Now I wish to create a loop which does this for each N

Also some of the N's are 0's and if this is the case I want these to be ignored/skipped

I am using R software

My best efforts are

```
for(i in 1:N){
        if(i != 0){
             par(mfrow=c(3,1))
            plot(x_whole[i,1,(1:T)], t='l')
        abline(h=mean(x_whole[i,1,(1:T)]), col='red')
        acf(x_whole[i,1,(1:T)], lag.max=190)
        pacf(x_whole[i,1,(1:T)], lag.max=190)

    }
    else{
        return 0 
        }
}
```

The data looks like

```
[,,1]
3.45    4    5    6    7
0       2    3    6    6
2.34    4    5    6    5

[,,2] 
4.56    4    5    6    7
4.43    2    3    6    6
0       4    5    6    5
```

etc.

I wish to have a 3x1 plot with the plot of [1,1,(1:T)] , [2,1,(1:T)] [3,1,(1:T)] as an output

Also it may be important to note the data in columns 3,4,5 are sorted

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your array looks like (for example using `dput`)? What's wrong with your previous efforts? What output did you expect instead? Also I have trouble understanding what you mean by "some Ns are 0".

Comment: As SimonG said, can you please provide some small part of your dataset (dput) or a fake dataset similar to yours? To start, you can make your code easier by putting a=x_whole[i,1,(1:T)] in the start of the loop and replace this in the rest. Second, how can N be zero if you're going from 1:N? Maybe you mean 0's in a (in which cas the all() function is handy)? Third, to skip a part of a loop check "next".

Answer (score 0):

try

```
for(i in 1:length(N)){
  if(i==0)
    {return 0} else
      {par(mfrow=c(3,1))
        plot(x_whole[i,1,(1:T)], t='l')
    abline(h=mean(x_whole[i,1,(1:T)]), col='red')
    acf(x_whole[i,1,(1:T)], lag.max=190)
    pacf(x_whole[i,1,(1:T)], lag.max=190)}}
```

i cant help any more without a sample of your data. could you please provide it as a vector/matrix in the format `data<-c(...)` or `data<-matrix(...,ncol=...,nrow=...)` thanks :)